How To Define Schema Type inside a array thype
i want a schema type like this,
DEFINE TABLE h SCHEMAFULL;
DEFINE FIELD items ON TABLE h TYPE array<object>;

inside this object there should be a type like this
 {
    active: bool,
    key: string,
    value: string,
    description: string | null
 };

how to create this schema.
Thanks for any help

you can do that via:
DEFINE TABLE h SCHEMAFULL;
DEFINE FIELD items ON TABLE h TYPE array<object>;

DEFINE FIELD items.*.key ON TABLE h TYPE string;
DEFINE FIELD items.*.value ON TABLE h TYPE string;
DEFINE FIELD items.*.description ON TABLE h TYPE option<string>;
DEFINE FIELD items.*.active ON TABLE h TYPE bool;

